# How to optimally reduce the poly count on a model with decimate modifier

Tags: modeling, polycount

I have a very high poly glass that I would like to reduce the poly count on:
[image]

I could use the Collapse option in the decimate modifier, but I don't like the solution it gives. I get poor geometry like this:

[image]

My best bet seems to be using the Un-Subdivide option in the decimate modifier. That gives me better geometry, but I don't want to make my glass into an octagon shape at the rim:

[image]

What options for reducing the poly count do I have?

Comment: Is it what Un-Subdivide gives with 4 Iterations? You could also use un Checker Deselect tool

Comment: Rather then to reduce a polycount of existing I would take a profile loop converted to curve and use screw modifier. like that you have controll over whole topology. For even distribution you can use Remedy, but it will degrade shape. The only Decimate reduce polys at places where they are not needed while keeps surface shape ... Just topo became messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *Un-Subdivide* doesn't give the expected result, you can dissolve some edges this way: Select a ring of edges (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>), then *Select > Checker Deselect*:

[image]

Choose the ratio of deselect in the *Operator Box* (by default it will be 1 out of 2), then *Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops*:

[image]

Then press <kbd>X</kbd> > Dissolve Edges or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>:

[image]

Result:

[image]